# What happens when force is applied too quickly?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, forces, volume

The scenario:

- An insulated box
- A piston on one side that can adjust the volume
- This is to determine the effects of a thermodynamic cycle

What's the mathematical explanation behind why the piston should not apply force too quickly?

My logical reasoning was that so "it wouldn't break the box open" but when I want to explain it mathematically, impulse or momentum can't fully explain it.

P.S. This was homework, but the due has already passed.

Comment: It may be referring to an isothermal process, which can happen if the piston is moved so slowly that heat can transfer through the walls and equalize the temperature.  A fast movement would approximate an adiabatic process, because heat does not have time to transfer

Answer (score 1):

One possibility: If the force is applied quickly, the piston will start accelerating, and then will dynamically move past the equilibrium. After some oscillations, the piston is going to stop. The work done by the external force will be $W_1=F\Delta x_1$. In contrast, if the force is applied slowly, the position of the piston will always adjust to the value of the force, and the work will be rather $W_2=\int_0^{\Delta x_1} F(x)dx$, where the force is going to be the function of the compression.